# Generics as object inside a function in Java

Tags: java, generics

How to use Generics inside the function in Java as Object. For example, I have a function that deletes nodes. When I try to call Generic's object procedure its trigger an error.

```
private <T> void deleteNodes(ArrayList<DepartmentHierarchy> newHierarchy) {

        StructureFacade structureFacade = StructureFactory.getClassInstance("DEPARTMENT");
        List<T> departmentModels = structureFacade.findAllByCompanyIdEquals(1L); // its Ok
        Set<Long> current_ids = new HashSet<>();
        for (T item: departmentModels) {  // its Ok
            current_ids.add(item.getId()); // Here is Error
        }
```

And then call the function:

```
this.<DepartmentModel>deleteNodes(newHierarchy);
```

Everything works fine until I call generic methods.

```
item.getId()
```

It throws the error:

```
Error:(168, 33) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getId()
  location: variable item of type T
Information:java: D:\HierarchyStructureController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Information:java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: Did you try the more traditional for-loop `for(int i=1; i<departmentModels.length; i++)`?

Comment: @Nikhil why would that make a difference?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Probably not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `getId()` on an object for which the compiler has no guarantee that the `getId()` method has been defined.  The compiler is doing its job, by stopping you from calling a method that might not exist.

The best way to handle this is to have some kind of interface in which the `getId()` method is listed, along with any other methods that your `T` objects need to have.  If you call your interface `Identifiable`, it might look like this.

```
public interface Identifiable {
    long getId();
}
```

Then any class that might be used for `T` should have `implements Identifiable` in its declaration.

Lastly, change your method signature to this.  This will enforce that `T` is always a class that implements your interface.  It also allows the compiler to accept that any object of class `T` will have the `getId()` method.

```
private <T extends Identifiable> void deleteNodes(ArrayList<DepartmentHierarchy> newHierarchy) {
```